# Deploying vagrant files?

Tags: deployment, vagrant

I've created a linux box using Puphet and got my vagrant box working. Is there a way I can take the entire configuration and then install everything the exact same way on a live server? I've checked out vagrant push but to my knowledge that only pushes up your code. What I want to do is have a completely blank live server and then to apply my vagrant file setup to it.

Comment: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/base.html

Comment: you can always run the puppet part directly on a bare server